What is the best way to generate menu titles with vue router?
I have the following routes defined in vue router:
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    params: { label: 'Home' },
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/path1',
    name: 'path1',
    params: { label: 'Path 1' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subpath1',
        name: 'path1-sub1',
        params: { label: 'Sub 1' },
        component: sub1,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath2',
        name: 'path1-sub2',
        params: { label: 'Sub 2' },
        component: sub2,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath3',
        name: 'path1-sub3',
        params: { label: 'Sub 3' },
        component: sub3,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/path2',
    name: 'path2',
    params: { label: 'Path 2' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subpath2',
        name: 'path2-sub1',
        params: { label: 'Sub 1' },
        component: sub1,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath2',
        name: 'path2-sub2',
        params: { label: 'Sub 2' },
        component: sub2,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath3',
        name: 'path2-sub3',
        params: { label: 'Sub 3' },
        component: sub3,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/path3',
    name: 'path3',
    params: { label: 'Path 3' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subpath3',
        name: 'path3-sub1',
        params: { label: 'Sub 1' },
        component: sub1,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath2',
        name: 'path3-sub2',
        params: { label: 'Sub 2' },
        component: sub2,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath3',
        name: 'path3-sub3',
        params: { label: 'Sub 3' },
        component: sub3,
      }
    ]
  },
]

I'm trying to make a v-for loop that generates a navigation menu for my app, but I'd like to add a title between path2 and path3 and have some way to quickly add titles in the future. Is there any way I can add a dummy item as a route or is there something vue router uses already to generate titles in menus?

Why not make an intermediate array with title objects. Then before you pass the routes to vue-router you filter out the unwanted title objects.

@Snake_py What do you mean by intermediate array? Add an array item to 'routes' wherever I need a title?

From what I understand you basically want to use this const routes array for a navigation bar with some additional UI sugar (titles). But titles cannot be consumed by vue-router. What I am saying is create a array for your UI const routes and then fitler this array before you pass it to vue-router (remove title objects).

Ah, I see! Ya, that makes sense! Thanks!

I am not supre sure if I understood you correctly. But form what I gather I would probably do something like this:
// I added an title "object"
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    params: { label: 'Home' },
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/path1',
    name: 'path1',
    params: { label: 'Path 1' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subpath1',
        name: 'path1-sub1',
        params: { label: 'Sub 1' },
        component: sub1,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath2',
        name: 'path1-sub2',
        params: { label: 'Sub 2' },
        component: sub2,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath3',
        name: 'path1-sub3',
        params: { label: 'Sub 3' },
        component: sub3,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/path2',
    name: 'path2',
    params: { label: 'Path 2' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subpath2',
        name: 'path2-sub1',
        params: { label: 'Sub 1' },
        component: sub1,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath2',
        name: 'path2-sub2',
        params: { label: 'Sub 2' },
        component: sub2,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath3',
        name: 'path2-sub3',
        params: { label: 'Sub 3' },
        component: sub3,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
     title: "I am some title",
     as: "h4"
  },
  {
    path: '/path3',
    name: 'path3',
    params: { label: 'Path 3' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'subpath3',
        name: 'path3-sub1',
        params: { label: 'Sub 1' },
        component: sub1,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath2',
        name: 'path3-sub2',
        params: { label: 'Sub 2' },
        component: sub2,
      },
      {
        path: 'subpath3',
        name: 'path3-sub3',
        params: { label: 'Sub 3' },
        component: sub3,
      }
    ]
  },
];

and then use the array as is for you UI and for vue-router you do:

const getRoutes = () => routes.filter(route => !route.title)


If this is not what you were looking for please clarify.
